# IDR and non IDR difference

Tags: h.264

What is the difference between IDR and non IDR frames?

What are 
"coded slice of non IDR picture" , 
"Coded slice Data partition A",
"Coded slice Data partition B",
"Coded slice Data partition C",
"Coded slice of an IDR picture" ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

IDR, slices, partitioning - you have them all defined formally right there in [specification](http://www.itu.int/ITU-T/recommendations/rec.aspx?rec=11466):

> 3 Definitions
>
> 3.62 **instantaneous decoding refresh (IDR) picture**: A coded picture in which all slices are I or SI slices that
>   causes the decoding process to mark all reference pictures as "unused for reference" immediately after
>   decoding the IDR picture. After the decoding of an IDR picture all following coded pictures in decoding
>   order can be decoded without inter prediction from any picture decoded prior to the IDR picture. The first
>   picture of each coded video sequence is an IDR picture.
>
> 3.27 **coded picture**: A coded representation of a picture. A coded picture may be either a coded field or a coded
>   frame. Coded picture is a collective term referring to a primary coded picture or a redundant coded picture,
>   but not to both together.
>
> 3.136 **slice**: An integer number of macroblocks or macroblock pairs ordered consecutively in the raster scan within
>   a particular slice group. For the primary coded picture, the division of each slice group into slices is a
>   partitioning. Although a slice contains macroblocks or macroblock pairs that are consecutive in the raster
>   scan within a slice group, these macroblocks or macroblock pairs are not necessarily consecutive in the raster
>   scan within the picture. The addresses of the macroblocks are derived from the address of the first
>   macroblock in a slice (as represented in the slice header) and the macroblock to slice group map.
>
> 3.137 **slice data partitioning**: A method of partitioning selected syntax elements into syntax structures based on a category associated with each syntax element.